# Find the minimum spanning tree of a tree embedded in the grid graph

Tags: algorithms, trees

Given a tree T, we need to map the vertex in T to a point (i,j) in the grid graph. And we want the edges don't cross over and minimize the sum of the edges' length.

Some only property I got is the degree of vertex v in T is no greater than 4.

Is it a NP-complete problem? Or there exists an algorithm that I don't know.

Comment: There are trees with maximum degree $4$ that are not embeddable in the infinite grid graph. One such tree is the skeleton of neopentane.

Comment: the edge can be a path in the grid graph. e.g. edge(1,2) can be 1xxxx2. the length is 4.